# how to access/get the variable in one javascript file to another javascript file

Tags: javascript, protractor, pageobjects, e2e-testing

How to access/get the variable from one javascript file to another javascript file.
like first.js contains a function first.js like below.

```
this.first = function(){
    var x = ['new','old'] 
}
```

now, I want to access the 'x' in another file say second.js
I have tried

```
var first = require('../first.js');  //path to the first.js file
console.log(first.x)
```

but getting the undefined value. 
i want to get/access the 'x' from first.js
I am using this for protractor E2E testing using page objects.

Comment: You need to export any functions or classes you want to use in another file. [See here](http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-module-exports-exports-node-js/) and [here](http://openmymind.net/2012/2/3/Node-Require-and-Exports/)

Comment: If you have reference to both js files in your page then any global variable value set in one file is available to other file

Comment: What about using another js file like common.js and use global variable(of course using global in js is not recommended). Another way is, if your 2 file in the same html, we can copy the values through a hidden field.

Comment: I want to access the variable 'x' in the function first of the first.js file from the second.js file

Comment: x is local variable to this.first expression make it global or make some method which can return x.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't matter on which js files the functions / variables are. After they are parsed, they all belong to the same `window`.

You get `undefined` when accessing `x` property because it is private. `x` exists only in the local scope of `first` function.

Here is an example of how you can get access to `x`.

```
var first = (function () {
    // private variables / functions
    var x = ['new', 'old'];

    // public properties (properties of "first")
    return {
        getX: function () {
            return x; // x.slice(0); if you want to send a copy of the array
        }
    }
}());
```

Answer (score 1):

The module loading system in node.js require you to use `module.exports` to expose your data types you want to share:

Your example would be re-written as follows:

```
// first.js

module.exports = {
   x : 'Something here',
   y : 'another item'
};
```

then on the other file

```
var first = require('../first.js');  //path to the first.js file
console.log(first.x)
```

See more details on [Node.js module loading system](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_modules)